# How to access a public state variable from another smart contract through an interface in Solidity

Tags: solidity, interfaces

I have a newbie question about accessing a public variable in another contract which was deployed. Contract `Escrow` needs to get `value` from another contract `DoubleTrade` deployed at an address. Here is the contract:

```
pragma "^0.7.0";

interface DoubleTrade {};  //<<==declare DoubleTrade. Is it the right way to declare ??? Do I need to declare getter function for public variable to be accessed? 

contract Escrow {


constructor () payable {
...
}

function getValueFromDoubleTrade(address _doubleTradeContractAddress) external returns 
(uint256) {
   DoubleTrade _double = DoubleTrade(_doubleTradeContractAddress);
   return _double.value();  //<<== value is a public variable in contract DoubleTrade
}

}
```

Is the code above going to work in solidity?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A public state variable is a combination of two things under the hood: a state variable and an external getter function. The getter is the only part relevant to your contract's ABI so that's what you put in the interface. You can then override it with an actual variable in your contract:

```solidity
interface IDoubleTrade {
    function value() external returns (uint);
}

contract DoubleTrade is IDoubleTrade {
    uint public override value;
}

contract Escrow {
    function getValueFromDoubleTrade(IDoubleTrade _double)
        external
        returns (uint)
    {
        return _double.value();
    }
}
```

A few details of note:

- Since solc 0.8.8 the `override` keyword is optional when overriding things from an interface. You still need it if you're on 0.7.x.
- Use contract types as function arguments to get full benefits of the strong typing. In the ABI it's still seen as an address but at least you won't pass in an incompatible contract by accident.